# jQuery append() @codeacademy

Tags: jquery, append

"Let's go ahead and append to our div with the .list class. We'll append a  with class="item", since we'll want a way to target our appended s later when we remove them. (A "to do" list is no good if we can't check things off it.)

We'll want the contents of our div to be the contents of our input field, which we saved in the variable toAdd. That means when we append, we'll want to append

> 'div class="item">' + toAdd + '/div'

INSTRUCTIONS

Go ahead and .append() a  with class="item" to the .list div of your HTML document, then MAKE SURE to click your button to add an item—the exercise will wait for you to do so!"

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>').append(".list");
});
```

Comment: And what is the issue you're seeing with this?

Comment: My words doesn't add to the list..


Oops, try again! Make sure to use .append() to add your .item to your .list!

Answer (score 1):

Wrong way round. You need the code you're appending to go in the brackets after the .append and you declare what you're appending it to in the first brackets:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.list').append('<div class="item">'+ toAdd + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, there's the `appendTo` method

Comment: Linking docs for [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) since they are so easily confused.

Comment: Still have problems with this..

"Oops, try again! It looks like you didn't append a new <div> to your .list."


`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
});`

Comment: Got it working, this is how it should be

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
    $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#button").click(function () {
    var toAdd = $('input[name=div.#item]').val();
    $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
    $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$(document).ready(function() { $("#button").click(function() { 
var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val(); 
$(".list").append('<div class="item">'  toAdd  '</div>'); }); });
```

note: just not to use "+" to concatinate and you will pass :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
    var $toAdd= $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $(".list").append('<div class="item">'+ $toAdd + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what the OP was doing wrong and why your answer works?